# Has the 'Type to find users' string match functionality been changed deliberately?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, users

Right now the [Type to find users](https://stackoverflow.com/users) search box on Stack Overflow unexpectedly returns matches for substrings starting from the beginning only, e.g.:

- Expected:

  - *Jeff* matches all Jeffs
  - *Jeff A* matches some Jeffs
  - *Jeff Atwood* matches the one and only only ;)
- Unexpected:

  - *eff* matches only users starting with Eff
  - *Atwood* matches only one user starting with Atwood

This appears to behave like that on SO only (revision: 2010.8.13.2), while some other sites like MSO here do still return arbitrary substring matches as desired (revision: 2010.8.13.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Yes, the user table on SO is too large to support unindexable `%foo%` style matching. We have switched to `foo%`.</s>

This is specific to SO because its user table is more than 10x larger than SU/SF, and 100x to 1000x larger than other SE 2.0 sites.

We build a special table to support partial display name matches now.