# Sudden sharp reputation drop problem: points disappeared and score lost (recalc?)

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-recalc

I just experienced a drop in rep. Maybe that's due to a rep recalc, but then I'd really like to see that in my recent activity, which shows no clue as to what happened. How do I find out exactly what happened?

(I already did a [manual recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/self-instigated-rep-recalc/71678#71678), which did not change my rep.)

**Edit**: user ire_and_curses posted a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80890/please-notify-us-when-a-reputation-recalc-occurs) concerning notifications when a rep recalc happens.

Comment: I lost about 300 as well, and am curious...

Comment: @Ned: did you try a manual recalc as well? (I know it's "risky", but I did it anyway.)

Comment: Seems more people have been affected: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80860/loss-of-reputation

Comment: Dammit! I went from 10,025 to 9,996. I want the moderator tools back!

Comment: @Cameron - that's just one vote away. You'll get it back in no time.

Comment: @Cameron: that must hurt ;)

Comment: What really hurt is I only got to 10k yesterday, so I was still checking out all the cool toys.

Comment: @Everybody, I feel sorry for you all, but please cut the "me too" comments.

Comment: hmmm, 16 votes in only one hour.... @larsmans if this keeps up you'll have all the rep you lost from SO back on meta. Still pretty crappy exchange though. :)

Comment: Just to troll everyone, I got like +9 reputation from this reputation recalc. I was wondering this morning why did my reputation went up.

Comment: Folks, please - this horse has been beaten to death. There was a global re-calculation. Some people went up, most of us went down. And then tomorrow happened.

Comment: Manual recalcs aren't "risky"; you can see exactly what's going to happen from the very page they are performed from.

Comment: @mmyers: ok, if I had studied `/reputation` I might have found out what it all means, but I was lazy and clicked it anyway.

Comment: I lost 0 as about one hour before the global recalc I recalced it manually, as I deleted one of my questions which was upvoted. I don't like it when my reputation drops automatically so I did this to prevent that. :)

Comment: I only lost 4, but it's nice to find out why. I thought I'd somehow gotten 2 downvotes on a question which then got deleted.

Comment: Interestingly, this helped me out.  I've been doing an occasional recalc anyway (usually to test for interesting corner cases, like migrating questions, etc).  I moved up the list, or rather I should say more than a dozen people fell below me.  One of these days reputation will actually be real time, and we'll never need to perform recalcs...

Comment: You all only lost pts..Wow i gained 4pts instead... :)

Comment: Did a 2012 global recalc just take place? Feb 25th 2012 is just about exactly a year  since Feb 27th 2011.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

We are running a global recalc right now across all Stack Exchange sites in preparation for showing leagues on the `/users` page, you can see more details (and suggest things!) in this question: [Redesigning the /users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80690/redesigning-the-users-page)

Note **no reputation rules have changed**, we're just doing a recalc to get your current week, month, quarter and year reputation calculated. If you experience a loss or gain, deleted users and such are just impacting your reputation if it has slipped off what it actually should be over time.

Comment: Oh dude that sucks so much, I was so excited to get to 1000 lol.

Comment: That's all fine and +1 to you, but also exactly what I expected. I'm more interested in why this isn't displayed on the "recent activity" page? It comes as quite a surprise to a lot of users...

Comment: Is there a chance of putting a notification bar in place to warn people when this happens? If nothing else it reduces confusion, and a spate of meta questions. Plus, and I may be biased, I'd find that infinitely more interesting than being told about a new badge, or whatever...

Comment: @larsmans - Hmm though to answer that one, maybe we could look at putting recalcs in there.  Overall though, it's not that we know your rep changed (though we do monitor, of course), more than we look at your *entire* history and update the totals based on it, so it's not viewed as a change in the system, but rather a sync.

Comment: @Nick: very well, accepted. Should I file a feature request?

Comment: so your rep points are removed when the user that gave them to you has been deleted ?

Comment: `"deleted users and such are just impacting your reputation if it has slipped off what it actually should be over time."` What exactly does this mean? I'm assuming deleted users' votes no longer count, but what do you mean by 'what it actually should be?'

Comment: I would be glad to be notified about decreasing as well.. I thought users down voted my answers, but taking into account loose of 76 points just for 1 hour... then looked at all my activities, investigated all other pages which I have... Well, imho it had to be done another way..

Comment: btw, if the reason is that SO "removed" our scores from deleted users, that sounds for me a bit that system should also remove questions and replies of deleted users... Last one sounds illogical which leads me to the point that first one is also not that perfect solution...

Comment: I don't think that deleted user's vote should be removed.
When they've asked the question and were answered, the vote for it.
I don't know what you need to do to get yourself deleted from this site, but why is it the blame of the rest of us.... Lost 100 Reps on this recalc....

Comment: @Dani One of the reasons users are deleted in the first place is because of vote fraud, so removing their votes is kind of necessary

Comment: @Michael Mrozek I don't think there is that much vote fraud out there. Especially when you consider how many people lost rep and how much all those people lost collectivly

Comment: @mcgrailm Obviously not all the rep lost today was due to that, but it's one reason users get deleted

Comment: I just noticed that Neil Butterworth (that pink star guy)'s reputation was recalculated too, he's back in the first page at 94.4k: http://stackoverflow.com/users/69307/anon

Comment: Is this the right place to point out that I got several hundred rep + from this? :D

Comment: The adjustment also got included in today's user league scores :)

Comment: Since users have the ability to recalc their own rep, you no longer need to do site-wide recalcs.  Why do you think that punishment is necessary?

Comment: @larsmans, I went looking for your feature request to upvote it and I didn't find it. Post a link when you get around to it.

Comment: @Lance - We'll soon (tomorrow) need the rep gains for week/month/quarter/year for all users...since these values didn't exist previously, they needed to be calculated.  That was the reason for this global recalc, we don't do this regularly...in fact it hasn't happened since March 2010, nearly a year.

Comment: @Nick Craver : I am sorry - I still do not understand the loss in reputation. So are you saying SO calculated the reps incorrectly the first time? Or is it that we lost votes by users who got deleted from the system? Then how did some people manage to gain reps?

Comment: @CoolBeans - There are a few cases, questions can be migrated for example, that's a rep change on both sides.  The same can be a reason for gaining rep, or the deletion of a user's *down* votes (those are often forgotten!).

Comment: @Nick Craver - Understood. Thanks for taking the time to answer :-)

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I've decided to support this one instead: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80890/please-notify-us-when-a-reputation-recalc-occurs

Comment: Users get deleted when they do not access their account for a certain amount of time (not sure how long). Why should their votes be removed from my rep, if they were active and then moved on to a community which doesn't adjust their privileges in stealth?

Comment: @user146674 I too was super excited to get to 1000 rep. Now that I know you can't really trust the number they show I sort of lost interest in rep chasing. Prob won't be around as much. Losing rep sucks and kinda killed my mojo.

Comment: @Dani I would have to agree with that. What does the user being deleted have to do with the rep they gave you? Just because they aren't around anymore doesn't mean you didn't deserve that rep.

Comment: @Chevex @User @SamGoody you can always see your "real" reputation at http://stackoverflow.com/reputation, and request an individual recalc.

Comment: @Pekka I know that. Doesn't change that deleted users' upvotes are removed from your rep. I think that is silly.

Comment: So 900 of my reputation on 7000 is from deleted users? Nice! Now I'm back to one year ago. Thank you.

Comment: What we certainly all want, is to have an historic of the reputation.

Comment: @Jaypal - You lost **200**, not **2000**, and this was due to lots of cross-voting from a user on the same IP address (which for all we know was you).  The moderator who saw you flagged for this behavior removed the cross-votes appropriately, upvoting a co-worker (or worse sock puppetry) isn't what's intended...upvoting is for *content* not *people* - and artificially inflating your rep is just not a good idea in general.

Comment: @NickCraver If that's the case shouldn't my account be suspended??

Comment: @Jaypal - Mods give the benefit of the doubt, if we were sure it was sock puppet voting and not between co-workers - yes, you'd be suspended.

Answer (score 23):

**Reputation score is denormalized, so it is expected for it to vary slightly from the "real" value over time.** We periodically recalculate everyone's reputation to bring it in sync, roughly once per year.

Some ways reputation can be affected without being updated live:

- a user is deleted; this deletes all their votes
- a post is deleted
- a post is migrated to another site

You can always check

`/reputation`

to see the live calculation of your reputation. Below that calculation you can optionally click "Trigger Reputation Recalc" to basically copy that live "total rep" to your user profile, making your profile reflect the current, most correct, value.

Comment: So I found out after checking meta when I suddenly lost all this rep. The problem is really that no notification is given and the FAQ doesn't mention recalc.

Comment: Second what larsmans said, but I also question the fairness of losing rep for deleted posts - surely rep honestly earned is honestly earned, this mechanism seems unduly arbitrary. (openness declaration: I lost a little more than 500 rep)

Comment: because a user is deleted doesn't make their vote any less valid and that's the problem I have I can understand a deleted or migrated post that makes sense to me on the either. Which makes me think if a user is deleted are his posts deleted as well ?

Comment: Agree w/ @mcgrailm - I don't know what constitutes grounds for deletion, but - except for sockpuppets - it seems to me that a vote from a deleted user isn't less legitimate just because that user's account has been deleted.

Comment: So cruel jeff. you could have notified. As there were no downvotes, figured somebody must be hating me enough now so that he is cancelling his previous upvotes. :)

Comment: I haven't checked for a formal feature-request as yet, but the (at the time of writing) 91 upvotes on my comment to @Nick Craver's answer (*Is there a chance of putting a notification bar in place to warn people when this happens?...*) suggests that the problem is less with the re-calc, more with the not-knowing. A notification, surely, wouldn't have taken that much effort?

Comment: This idea that deleted users' votes shouldn't count doesn't make sense to me - it seems kind of like asking for a recount of the Presidential election a year later because maybe enough voters for one candidate have died to switch the result to another candidate.

Comment: "[...] so it is expected for it to vary slightly [...]" I lost 900 on 7200 over whatever happened. Is that slightly? Does it mean I didn't earn it? Was it all fake? 12% of my work, non existing? /reputation won't even tell me what happened. It just disapeared instantly.

Comment: @coin in your case it's likely two highly voted answers to "do programmers need a union" and "what music do programmers listen to". So yes, this was fake from my perspective. :)

Comment: @jeff Thanks for the clarification. I understand that those questions where not necessarily programming specific by some standards that evolved with time. However, let me tell you why this still feel like a slap in the face. Early starters, all answered some of those questions when people considered them pertinent, and they trusted the answers by upvoting them. Yes, some people cashed incredible amount of rep because of that. However, those persons are still trusthworthy, after all, they are the one who helped create this community since the beggining. I feel it is wrong to punish them today.

Answer (score 2):

I thought they had committed to not doing another onerous rep recalc like the last one they did.  I guess I thought wrong.  What's sad is that they don't even have a good reason like last time where it was because they changed the rep gained from questions (though they could have worked around it if they had chosen too).

Comment: the workaround would mean all the internal rep leagues we are launching on the /users page would be off by a bit of rep. Sure we could have accepted that, but it would lead to other issues.

Comment: @waffles, if you mean the 'top users' leagues on [SE](http://stackexchange.com/leagues), I'm not sure why any recalc would be needed since the base amount doesn't matter, only the gain?

Comment: It really wasn't technically feasible to avoid a recalc here (nor was it before).  We committed to very few if any reputation **rules** changes, and they haven't changed with this recalc.  What this did was sync your rep to what it should be based on the votes you have in the system.  Try and keep in mind you'd get the same effect by going to `/reputation` and clicking yourself.  We have a good reason for this, you can find the question about it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80690/redesigning-the-users-page

Answer (score 1):

I don't generate as much as others and so on StackOverflow.com my loss was just 27 points, I think.

Perhaps though for the general user who doesn't visit meta, after a recalc you should be allowed to "diff" which will show which reps you had got taken away.

By the way, if you capped, you could possibly now receive reps you didn't previously to take you up to the cap, I presume.

I was lucky enough to reach the cap yesterday. Very rare though for me.

Comment: You should post this as a separate feature request; I don't think you'll get many eyeballs on this answer.

Comment: Actually, looks like someone already has requested this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80892/possible-to-see-what-changes-caused-reputation-adjustments-during-the-recalculati