# Please notify us when a reputation recalc occurs

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, notifications, reputation-recalc

As summarised succintly in [David Thomas' comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/sudden-sharp-drop-in-reputation-find-out-reason-recalc/80865#80865):

> Is there a chance of putting a notification bar in place to warn people when this happens? If nothing else it reduces confusion, and a spate of meta questions. Plus, and I may be biased, I'd find that infinitely more interesting than being told about a new badge, or whatever...

Comment: or a message in the users inbox or recent activity page - I don't mind my reputation changing, but this would reduce the "I lost ?? reputation without reason" questions.

Comment: +1 after receiving dozens of upvotes from confused users on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/sudden-sharp-drop-in-reputation-find-out-reason-recalc

Comment: Also, could the thread become a sticky on Meta?

Comment: Would be also nice to explain where is the difference coming from.

Comment: ...dammit, I totally wish **I'd** posted this as a feature-request, now... =/

Answer (score 3):

In the rare cases that we do global style recalcs, you can expect a notification banner here on meta, placed manually.

Beyond that, I don't think we'll be doing anything else with this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this feature has been implemented.

The last time there was a recalc, a notification was placed on top of every page at [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)

saying something like "Lost some reputation points? A system wide reputation recalculation has occured"

Comment: Well no, that message was put there *after* Meta was flooded with 'Mah precious rep iz gone, wat to do' questions. It's not automated and there's no guarantee that the team will do this the next time it happens

Comment: @Yi If it gets automated then the problem might be solved