# How about a message letting us know the reason for large changes to our reputation points?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Please notify us when a reputation recalc occurs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80890/please-notify-us-when-a-reputation-recalc-occurs)

Last time I logged in to Meta Stack Overflow, my reputation points were over 400. Now it's back under 300, and I don't have any idea why. One possibility is that I have a vote fan who committed [vote fraud](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) on my behalf on Meta Stack Overflow (probability of this is near 0, I think). Another is that there was a [reputation recalculation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/) triggered somehow, but since I haven't been too active on Meta Stack Overflow, I cannot image that having a serious impact. Yet another is that there is a new limit on points from asking a question (many of my recent reputation points came from a recent question I asked). Or it could be something else entirely.

While I would really like to know in this case what happened, just for curiosity, it seems like it might be a good idea to let users know the reason for a drop (or increase) in reputation points of more than 100 points or 20% or some other reasonable threshold. My guess is that there are a limited number of reasons for such a sudden change, and having a message in my Stack Exchange INBOX tab at the top letting me know the reason would have been nice.

Comment: I just lost my view vote count priv... :(

Comment: Amen. A simple notice would save a lot of head-scratching and "churn".  My rep dropped 200 odd points for no visible reason. So, I spent many minutes searching and was about to open my own question when I refreshed and saw yours.

Comment: @PengOne: Aw, man :(

Comment: @YOU: Here the reason is _much more_ than a simple recalc.

Comment: At least there was a *notice* under the banner. Much appreciated.

Comment: Look on the bright side: this question has been upvoted so many times you're probably gonna wind up with more rep than before. :-)

Comment: @George: I was just pondering the irony of that. Of course, once the rep limit from questions goes into effect, I'll probably be right back here again.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yeah, there should be notice, but I wonder how they could for this case, looks like they synchronize rules to meta too.

Now questions could only earn +5 instead of +10

```
answer is voted up   +10    
question is voted up     +5 
answer is accepted   +15     (+2 to acceptor)
post is voted down   -2  (-1 to voter)
```

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Thanks. This must be it. Although, I must say, I liked that questions were worth more than answers on Meta since they seem to me to be more valuable.

Comment: I was going to post a pre-emptive question but it felt like I would be rep whoring... I lost 4000 rep today though ... sad day for

Comment: Regarding notice, see this feature request http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80890/please-notify-us-when-a-reputation-recalc-occurs

Comment: @waffles, I was so close to getting 20k at least on one site... this made me a sad panda

Comment: You heard it here first

Comment: @waffles: I think you shouldn't have bothered. After all, pre-emptive questions are only half-whores now.

Answer (score 11):

I think they changed the weight for upvotes to questions from 10 to 5. The [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) now reads:

> question is voted up       +5

Answer (score 9):

We amended question rep on meta so it is in line with the rest of the sites. So now, upvotes on questions are worth **5 points**.

<strike>Additionally, we are planning another change to rep that restricts the amount of rep you can get from questions only, see: [Should we cap reputation gained from questions at +2000?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81929/should-we-cap-reputation-gained-from-questions-at-2000/81947#81947) for details.</strike>

We wanted to make sure all our sites have consistent rep rules, to avoid confusion.

Comment: I would complain about the fact that no one has been confused, except I didn't lose too much and I moved up in the rep rankings, so *meh*. *Ignore this comment.*

Comment: I can appreciate that. However, I find that, on meta, the questions are more interesting than the answers for the most part. Good questions abound on the other sites, but here they take more thought. That's why I liked the old system. That said, consistency is definitely a good goal. Thanks for letting me/us know.

Comment: Strange that it took so long for meta to implement this change, it's been like that for ages on SO

Comment: Thanks for adding the notice bar, but what is that [wisdom about over consistency](http://www.bartleby.com/100/420.47.html)? (^_^)

Comment: @waffles, Re "we are planning another change to rep that restricts the amount of rep you can get from questions only": Can you say which of the versions is going to come? We had a short conversation about different ratios over there.

Comment: @Hendrik, my answer is the one we are going with

Comment: @waffles: Thanks for the instant reply. I'm somewhat disappointed since in the comments over there you wrote "I am comfortable changing to 1000/500".

Comment: Minor nit: the rep-change-since-last-view in the envelope replacement didn't get recalculated so it says I have +9 when it's now just +4. Not that I expect it's worth fixing that because you won't be changing rep scoring very often.

Comment: @hendrik I will talk to Jeff 1000/500 is ok IMHO

Comment: @waffles: Great, thank you very much!

Comment: Two solutions looking for problems... I hope you guys know what you're doing :)

Comment: Changing the way rep is calculated all the time is just a sad thing.  It wasn't broken before, so it didn't need to be changed.  Meta SO is it's own beast in a number of ways, there's no reason it can't be different in these ways also.

Comment: By "consistent rep rules" you mean "except that on meta.stackoverflow.com we track your rep separately from the main site unlike every other meta site in the stack."

Comment: meta.SO is not just the meta site for SO; it's the meta site for other sites as well.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - are you disagreeing with me or pointing out another inconsistency?

Comment: Also, by "consistent rep rules" you mean "except stackapps, because, seriously, who the hell posts questions on stackapps? People _abusing_ the site, that's who!"

Comment: @tvanfosson I am just stating a fact; if I were disagreeing with somebody, I would report with whom I am disagreeing.

Comment: @Hendrik, @waffles: It seems that proposal is alread outdated: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/86165/should-we-require-minimum-reputation-to-continue-asking-questions

Comment: @Lance I agree... and: *that* (changing the rules all the time) is confusing, much more so than "this site gives different rep"... which is the norm with all the beta sites, they have different rules too, and no-one claims it's "confusing" (and aren't we half-way intelligent beings?)

Answer (score 2):

There was an announcement here when the main site received a site-wide recalc. [Related post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/sudden-sharp-reputation-drop-problem-points-disappeared-and-score-lost-recalc) Then again that announcement might have been to curb the influx of "I lost N rep!" posts and nothing more.

I suppose there'll be another announcement put up shortly to let us know of the change cited by the other answers. [See this feature request.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80890/please-notify-us-when-a-reputation-recalc-occurs)

Comment: Announcement: Your rep just changed. Kthxbye.

Answer (score 1):

Surprised nobody mentioned this yet, but whenever there is something different here I first check this:
[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446)

The reputation change is right now on top. :)

(This does not mean I don't agree with the feature request though, just a way to see what has changed quickly)

Comment: The relevant information was added to that answer well **after** this question was posted.

Comment: @Brock, yep by YOU (lol) - noticed that too late..