# Show me the rep!

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Now that there are some wide reaching [changes to the rep system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85974/89035) (and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81929/89035)). It would be nice to have a simple way to seeing how your rep is distributed between answers, questions and edits.

A breakdown on your profile page for instance.

Answer (score 1):

A simple summary of

```
Rep from questions:   Votes separate from accept points
Rep from answers:     Votes separate from accepts and bounties.
Misc Rep:             Bonus and negatives from bounties.
```

Would be nice and would also be a good way to show where limits might be placed on max question rep with links or tool-tips explaining the details.