# The reputation change notice doesn't link to a discussion on why this reputation change is necessary

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta

> We wanted to make sure all our sites have consistent rep rules, to avoid confusion.

So I understand why the reputation changed, but to me this is a poor argument. I thought it made sense that questions on meta generated more rep, since questions are more important on meta.

Here are a few reasons why it would make sense to change it back:

- On meta it's very common that the questions have more upvotes than the answers. On SO it's the other way around. This indicates that questions are more valuable on meta.
- Answers on meta often just include suggested changes to the suggestion made in the question. I don't see how suggested changes are more valuable than the original suggestion.

It is possible that there has been a thorough discussion on this topic and if so I think the notice (or the answer that is linked) should provide a link to that discussion. Instead the only thing that is linked is a suggestion to cap reputation for questions, which would make even less sense for meta.

If you haven't discussed the reputation change before performing it... Well, let's just say that would be bad and weird.

**UPDATE:** If anyone could provide a link to the discussion that would be awesome. I want to know what led up to this decision.

**EDIT:** Since the notice is gone, here's the link: [How about a message letting us know the reason for large changes to our reputation points?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85974/how-about-a-message-letting-us-know-the-reason-for-large-changes-to-our-rep/85988#85988)

Comment: Also, if I'd care about rep, posting bug reports used to be rewarded a bit more. (But I can see the confusion about different rules.)

Answer (score 3):

I agree that questions have much more value than answers on Meta.  But that is why they have more votes as you already pointed out.

Since a poster is getting more votes on meta for a question I don't think they need the extra 5 point bonus.

Having consistent rep rules across the sites will make the site more usability and in fact should help reduce the number of questions on meta.

Comment: Is the number of questions on meta a problem?

Comment: @ErikB, Questions about how things work are an indication that things might not be simple enough.  Related: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/07/meta-is-murder.html

Comment: True, but reducing the reputation gained by questions isn't the solution. The solution is simplifying stuff. Unless you just want to create an illusion of having solved the problem.

Comment: @ErikB, yes and reducing the reputation from question on meta to match the other sites is "simplifying stuff", at least in my eyes.

Comment: Touché. You've made a good argument, but I'd still like to see the discussion that lead to this reputation change, before I can accept an answer.