# Can we get a *real* rep log/audit?

Tags: feature-request, reputation-audit

I'm pretty sure I was above 300 rep here, now I'm back at 200+. Yes, I'm small fish.  Which means every point counts ;-)

Basically, I'm annoyed that there's some rep changes that are not logged, at all, all you get is... well, nothing. Just a thought "I'm sure I had more rep" or even a feeling (like when you were, as I was, a few days off the site) "I *think* I had more rep"

*Why* did my rep (if it did) decrease? Maybe there *are* means to see it, but those are (quite) certainly not available to me.

"If you log, log everything, or the log's useless." You can quote me on that.

Comment: Rep change was because of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85974/how-about-a-message-letting-us-know-the-reason-for-large-changes-to-our-rep/85988#85988

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way reputation is calculated has [recently changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange):

> 2011-04-04: Question up-vote rules now sync to meta and can only earn +5 instead of +10.

If I've understood the change, then the reputation you have *from question votes* was 230 and is now 115, which would account for the reputation change you've seen.

The main point is that *reputation is not like a bank balance where previous transactions remain forever unchanged**, it's more like the **result of a formula**. The formula has been changed so the result has changed. If it was done in a "bank balance" way, every time the formula/rules for calculating reputation were altered a balancing "transaction" would need to be recorded against *every* affected user to detail what the adjustment was and what caused it. That would cause a massive amount of complexity for very little gain. [After all](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq):

> Reputation is completely optional. Normal use of [Meta] Stack Overflow — that is, asking and answering questions, or submitting an edit — does not require any reputation whatsoever.

Answer (score 5):

At the moment, the way the system reacts to rule changes and removed content is a bit like time travel. New rules get applied as if they had *always been that way*.

The downside is that there can be unexplained reputation changes sometimes. That can be annoying, no doubt.

However, the upside is that this way protects everyone's sanity. Imagine a reputation report taking every rule change into account as a separate item. You, reading the rep report, and the developers maintaining that monster would go *crazy*. It would become as complicated as a massive ten-year tax calculation.

Is it really worth that just in order to be able to know *which* specific circumstance I lost my rep to?

Comment: You just state, you don't give evidence.  Sorry, not convincing.  Aside from that, at least a "rep decreased by AMOUNT due to REASON", as a lump change, would go a long way.

Comment: @jae evidence of what? The "lump change" idea is a good one, though, that should be doable and help a lot. That said I don't really see the big deal either way - in my eyes, reputation points are fun, but ultimately meaningless. I lost some 6,000 points through the change recently here on Meta. So what?

Comment: Evidence for the claim that it would be "a monster".

Comment: But I found that the rep tab on stackoverflow.com does track even that change (it even tracks changes to rep before you get to 200, very interesting page)

Comment: @jae If every rule change, and every deletion of an answer you had upvotes on would be tracked and documented, the resulting list would become a *hideous* monster. I don't think that point needs any further evidence :) The reputation stats page is very detailed, but it does not track the kinds of changes we're talking about. If there wasn't a significant change I missed