# What happened to all my reputation points?

Tags: support, reputation, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How about a message letting us know the reason for large changes to our rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85974/how-about-a-message-letting-us-know-the-reason-for-large-changes-to-our-rep)

I just noticed that I'm now under 5000 reputation points. I was almost on 7000 here on Meta. I don't know when this was changed, but I'd say it happened within the past month.

My Stack Overflow account, however has not been affected, nor has any of my other accounts. Why are all my reputation points gone?

Comment: Is there any activity on your profile reputation tag?

Comment: @Phil, no. I remember there being a largeish disparity between `/reputation` and my actual reputation. But even in `/reputation` it reported my reputation to be I believe about 6000 or 5500 last I checked.

Comment: It was a hosed-up deal, I lost over 4k on Meta.  Guess we just don't rate.

Answer (score -4):

Ah, of course another unannounced reputation change. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85974/how-about-a-message-letting-us-know-the-reason-for-large-changes-to-our-rep/85988#85988)

Comment: It's a little silly to post an answer complaining about an unannounced rep change in one sentence and linking to the announcement in the other

Comment: @Mich it wasn't an announcement. It was another user complaining about changes to reputation.

Comment: No, @Michael, it's another way to get the message across that nobody is getting.  And of course, he probably found the answer after he posted the question; that's happened to me many times.