# How to find out what was downvoted or why reputation droppped?

Tags: discussion

Today my reputation dropped from 19,151 to 19,149.

I would like to review this but I've no clue where to look.

EDIT: 
I checked https://stackoverflow.com/reputation but there also is no indication of a downvote. Should I trigger a reputation recalc?

I can't trace down my fault which was worth to be downvoted on SO.

```
-- 2011-12-14 rep +40   = 18887     
 2   8526824 (10)
 2   2056326 (10)
-- 2011-12-15 rep +20   = 18907     
 2   8487728 (10)
 2   8456462 (10)
 2   8532878 (10)
 2   8532878 (10)
 2   8532878 (10)
 2   8532878 (10)
 2   8532878 (10)
-- 2011-12-16 rep +70   = 18977
```

Comment: You've got 2 years and 20k on SO and never noticed [your reputation overview](http://stackoverflow.com/users/241590/stacker?tab=reputation)...?

Comment: I don't follow; where did you ask for support? Did you mean that Meta rejected the first draft of this question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/reputation , `Ctrl+F`, `(-2)`, `Enter` (you might also want to search for `[-2]`)

Comment: @Chichiray Yes, I checked this http://stackoverflow.com/users/241590/stacker but there is no indication.

Comment: @stacker Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/users/241590/stacker?tab=reputation&sort=time It seems like you got your last downvote on Dec 10th, on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455390/how-to-implement-roundup-function-in-java/8455405#8455405

Comment: @PopularDemand Yes probably I didn't provide the the minimum of required length of text.

Comment: If you don't see anything obvious in your reputation history, it's possible that you had your reputation recalculated. Did you recently undergo any account merging or the like?

Comment: I issued a rep recalc on your account. You "lost" some rep because of that, but it should normalize your reputation. Keep an eye on future rep changes.

Comment: Come on, stacker, it seems you were [much more relaxed about reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85974/how-about-a-message-letting-us-know-the-reason-for-large-changes-to-our-rep/86295#86295) some time ago!

Comment: You did take into account that the downvote *might* have been removed/revoked/taken back, right?

Comment: @Bobby I noticed the -2 and checked http://stackoverflow.com/reputation which did not show the change neither my profile showed a -2 for the current day. Therefore I asked and was treated like a moron.

Comment: Then you should have taken a screenshot of what you mean, so that we can easily recognize what you want.

Comment: @Bobby I've added the last lines of my reputation history, as you can see there is no indication of a downvote. Could it be that a split vote +8 leads to -2 that is not listed here?

Comment: The real question is: Where the heck did you see the -2 and is it still there?! If yes, make a screenshot!

Comment: @Bobby My total rep was 19.151 and all of a sudden it was 19.149 I haven't seen the -2 anywhere else. That was the question . Laster on a rep recalc was performed. I didn't expect something like that so I haven't made a screenshot.

Comment: Now we're talking...most likely answers got deleted which you've downvoted.

Comment: @Bobby thanks that would explain this strange thing.

Comment: No, @Bobby, if something stacker downvoted was deleted, then their reputation would have *increased*, wouldn't it? The only reason for a -2, apart from a downvote that we cannot find, would be that stacker un-accepted an answer. But I guess that did not happen either: Google cache shows no accepted answers for stacker's 3 questions that have no accepted answer when the above was posted, and none of stacker's questions have been migrated. (And I don't know if migration would also migrate reputation.)

Comment: @Arjan: Uh, yeah, right. Maybe some answers were undeleted? That would explain it.

Comment: @Arjan: Or maybe an accepted answer to one of his questions was deleted fro some reason...or the whole question.

Comment: True, @Bobby. Given the quality of stacker's posts I didn't think about deletion (and I couldn't find migrations to sites on which stacker has an account too). But [deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean/5222#5222) of a zero-vote question from stacker, with an accepted answer, might explain it. (I'm not sure reputation is cancelled then; deleting my own upvoted answers does not remove reputation until I trigger a recalc?)

Comment: @Arjan: Maybe that happened quite some time ago and the system triggered a recalc today. Hard to say, and hard to track, even for a dev.

Comment: No, the recalc that was triggered by a moderator yesterday made stacker lose much more than 2 rep, @Bobby. Well, we'll never know I guess!

Comment: @Arjan Deletions don't usually cause an instant change in reputation. Since the OP lost a bunch of rep with the recalc, it doesn't look like rep was in sync either (ie: recently recalculated). So my best guess is that stacker unaccepted an answer.

Comment: @Null​อ_อUser, that might be true, though the Google caches of the 3 questions without an accepted answer didn't show accepted answers at the time the cache was saved either. But I indeed think you're right about that being the only case where the reputation would change right away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Either you check your reputation page int he profile.]
[image: Or you check that awesome hover-thingy.]

Comment: No, it was two (2) hours ago!

Comment: What you emphasized on my profile was a split vote. The -1 on yours was clearly a downvote that I would have regconized on my profile. Anyway thanks for your time.

Comment: What is f.e.? I feel like I'm missing out on something.

Comment: @jwiscarson: probably "for example"; I see `f.e.` used more often here than the more standard [`e.g.`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.g.#exempli_gratia). Not sure why.

Comment: @jwiscarson: Since I don't have access to his Super-Awesome-Account-Hover-Thingy(tm) I used mine, and outlined that downvotes are displayed there, too, hence. the `for example`.

Comment: @stacker: The last downvote you received was on 10th Dec...according to that reputation page on your profile.

Comment: I understand now -- I'd just never seen "f.e." used to abbreviate "for example". "e.g." is the more standard use, as sarnold pointed out.

Comment: @jwiscarson: I'm not a native English speaker, so that might be why I'm more used to f.e. .

Comment: Yeah, we totally screwed up our language. Don't blame me; I wasn't there when they decided to use Latin for stuff like this.

Answer (score 5):

Look at your profile (click on your user name in the top bar), and you will have access to your reputation history. You should see there if you had an answer that got downvoted.