# How can I view my downvotes

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, reputation-graph, information-display

How do I view my downvoted answers and questions? I don't want to know *who* is doing the downvoting, just what is getting downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the red envelope next to your user name.  You can look at the exact questions you loss rep on. (Your downvote or from someone else).

Comment: Do I lose reputation by downvoting other StackOverflowers' reputation ...?

Comment: @5arx, yes you lose 1 rep for each downvote you cast.

Comment: Ha ha ha that'll be what it is then - I'll have to be nicer in future. Thanks very much, I don't know how I missed that useful bit of knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43005#43005) by Jeff.

Comment: Thanks. Its not quite what I was looking for because it displays downvotes the same way regardless of whether I downvoted or someone downvoted me. Short of trawling through all the referenced posts to manually make the distinction i can't see a way to usefully use this? Or am i missing something ...?

Comment: I'm not sure this is showing everything? Over the weekend I lost  around 30 reputation points, but there seems to be no record of this...

Comment: Click on your username on the top, then look at the "reputation" tab. This graphs all your answers votes (up and down) and if you select a period (90 days max) you can scroll down in the left pane and see which posts got the most downvotes. Also, rep is a funny beast, the recalc will cause you to "loose" some rep.

Comment: Also, sitewide recalc is currently running: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/sudden-sharp-drop-in-reputation-find-out-reason-recalc/80865#80865

Comment: Ahhh must be recalc-related - I've checked everywhere you and @jzd suggested but can't see any pertinent downvotes. Oh well...