# Eeeek! Why do you change core functionality without asking us for feedback first?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, global-inbox

So you guys are all familiar with what happened with the envelope and the [website design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83600/eeeek-why-is-stackoverflow-naked).

Since the website is very mature now and people don't really expect experimental/unfinished changes being deployed on all websites, I'm just wondering why you don't make a meta post asking for feedback **before** deploying the feature on high volume websites such as stackoverflow.com.

waffles has done this a few times and I think it always worked out great and no one was angry, so why isn't this always done?

Comment: Website layout?

Comment: waffles [is not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72202/moderator-dashboard-help-us-help-you-help-us-all) [the only](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76621/new-stack-exchange-search-try-it-out) [one who](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80690/redesigning-the-users-page) [provisions out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) [for new implementations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81929/should-we-cap-reputation-gained-from-questions-at-2000).

Comment: @Grace: yes, it was more of an example. What I'm wondering is why this isn't always done =)

Comment: Can we stop the **Eeeek** title meme now?  It's rapidly losing it's novelty.

Comment: I admit that **Eeeek** is starting to lose steam, but it's still giving me micro-chuckles.

Comment: Especially with the use of Eeeek the cat, it gave me reason to laugh again. However, it's easy to be abused for attention and not for the laughs.

Answer (score 20):

For the same reason Facebook doesn't. If they did, it would end up like this: [The Process (a.k.a. Designing The Stop Sign Video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wac3aGn5twc)

I'm not quite sure why everyone thinks they have an equal say in what the developers paid by the company that has financial obligations to meet push out to the site.

Imagine if all of *your* users wanted to you to run EVERY change to the system past them first.

Comment: Facebook has done it before though. They ran new.facebook.com for quite awhile to gather user feedback before pushing the changes on to everyone. They have given the option to preview new designs, the new photo galleries, etc. Facebook seems to have learned from its history of user outrage that it is better to ease users into major changes.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why everyone thinks they have an equal say in what the developers paid by the company that has financial obligations to meet push out to the site. => Probably because of their motto =)

Comment: +1 - "You can please some of the people all of the time, but you can't please all of the people all of the time."

Comment: Funny you would say that; that kind of UI churn is one of the reasons I don't actually use facebook much. I also think that to compare SO to facebook like this is unfair; SO seems to have less gratuitous rug-pulling by at *least* one order of magnitude.

Answer (score 10):

Simple answer is for the same reason that they don't maintain an official changelog. There's a lot that gets changed. Tiny things, small scale things, then big scale things. The perspective of whether it's big or small depends on the person looking at it.

For example, the CSS change? I shrugged it off because it was pretty minor to me. But given the reaction, there's a lot of people in both camps - some found it minor, some found it major. Both camps reacted differently - some felt it was minor but could use some big changes, others felt it was a major change but also shrugged it off. It's not even like there's a universal opposition or appreciation in either camp.

Could the decision to pre-advert or not be considered arbitrary? Perhaps it can be. Fact is, not everything goes through the community because making *everything* go through the community would probably hold up development significantly. By asking only about the biggest of items and letting much smaller things just get pushed, it accomplishes a lot more in less time.

Comment: Some people just need something, anything to rage against while they sit in their bunks doling out some of that armchair revolution

Comment: In the month of February alone, there were [21 changes documented in our community FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange), including flag weight, migration checks that remove tags, backticks in comments changing, the Strunk & White badge change, and the location of the logout link. Some people may consider one or more of these core functionality, and yet not one of the 21 was put first to community review. We had minor tussles, but otherwise we got nearly one new feature per day.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there were arguments about every feature you listed. Wow we whine a lot

Comment: @Michael For the most part, if you think about it though, the people behind each of those arguments... were the big voices of the movements ever the same people?

Answer (score 9):

This is not always done because *not all features are experimental*.

We have strong feelings that certain features are necessary for the network and sites to grow, and are not experimental but *inevitable*.

Of couse we are always willing to listen to feedback in either case and make adjustments, but what you think of as an "experimental change" we may think of as "essential and necessary change".

I can't really define those terms for you, only you can, so what you're asking for is effectively impossible.

Comment: Why not get feedback from us first, then rollout the change after you've fixed bugs/design flaws we've discovered? For instance the whole envelope bit could've been made a lot better if the envelope was kept for a while, and you let us see the new replacement, put in suggestions and you implement those suggestions, THEN deploy it. Rather than deploy and then get suggestions/complaints and then implement changes when the community gets fed up.

Comment: @earlz we always plan to implement changes based on feedback, being "fed up" has nothing to do with it. Shipping is a feature, and it's the best way to get feedback.

Comment: Actually, I've become quite fond of the new layout.  At first I was a bit confused, but then I realized that I can still see all my responses and upvotes/downvotes by clicking on the arrow by my name and clicking "reputation".

Comment: @Jeff: Well, shipping is a _great_ feature, but I understand Earlz suggestion as follows: ship the new feature _and keep the old one for a while_. That would have been easily possible here. I think enough users would have tested the new feature even with the old envelope being around.

Comment: @hendrik the old feature was, and still is, available. Nothing was removed.

Comment: @Jeff: No, it's only partially available. The _notification_ of favorite changes was removed, and also the _link_ to the `/recent` page where one can find the changes. That's more than "nothing". (I hope some of that will be integrated in the new drop-down, which is already quite nice.)

Comment: @Jeff: Now the `/recent` page _is_ removed, and there's no proper substitute for it's "favorites" tab yet. (The "favorites" tab on my profile only tells me _that_ there were changes, but it's a lot less clear about _were_ to find them.)