# Can the users page please revert to column-major order

Tags: feature-request, users, design

As I probably don't pay as much attention to meta as I should, I missed the [call for proposals on a redesign of the users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80690/redesigning-the-users-page).  I have no big quarrel with the changes, except the sort order has changed from column major to row major.
In other words,

- In the old page, users who were adjacent in reputation (or whatever) were displayed in the same column, and because the gaps between rows are small, it was easy to scan up and down one column to find out who is where in reputation order.
- In the new page, users who are adjacent in reputation are displayed in the same row, and because the gaps between columns are large, it is very tedious to try to scan across a single row.

Reverting to the other order will improve usability.  That's why `ls` lists things in column-major order.

Please go back.

Comment: well, users asked for it to be *changed* to the other order so.. I propose some sort of [conflict resolution system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors)

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks for the response.  Damn those other users, anyway!  What I get for not paying attention.