# Users in stackoverflow show wrong reputation

Tags: support, reputation, users

In stackoverflow if we go to users tab the reputation is different than when we go the users profile.

It looks that the profile shows the correct reputation.

Comment: Do you mean the roundings?

Comment: Are you on the "All" tab or "Month" (which is the default)?

Comment: I am in default 
For example I clicked users tab - first name came up Jon Skeet with reputation 1033 but when I am viewing profile it is showing 559,370.

Comment: Seems that down voters here are having problems dealing with the truth. Just like a lot of other meta down voters elsewhere, it's just that it's really obvious here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably looking at the reputation accumulated this week:

[image: Screenshot of the users page tabs]

The page used to show all reputation by default, but it was a bit boring always seeing the same people, so when the page was [redesigned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80690/redesigning-the-users-page) the tabs were added to show reputation accrued over different spans of time. Click the "[all](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all)" link to show total reputation